# Show more/less items in Visual-Studio intelliSense Member-List

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm always wondering why i have just ten items in the visual-studio intellisense Member-list. I have big screen for more items. Searching a function in a big class can be very annoying.

The msdn Helpsite was no able to answer my question, but shows in the first picture that it is possible.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/exbffbc2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I'm using VS2008 / VS2010 / VS2012 with no extensions and work with cpp code.